# Does a JPA persist() operation always include all the mapped entity fields in the generated INSERT statement?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

My question is related to [Is there a way to prevent null values from being persisted while allowing others through?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088743/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-null-values-from-being-persisted-while-allowing-others) and [Is it necessary to set all the fields of the entity classes when using JPA to persist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010224/is-it-necessary-to-set-all-the-fields-of-the-entity-classes-when-using-jpa-to-pe), but goes in the opposite direction.

Instead of preventing null values from being persisted, I would like to be sure that null values are consistently used in the generated `INSERT INTO` statement of a persist operation so that I can detect `NOT NULL` constraint violations in my application code.

The reason is because my team has a convention on the underlying database (Postgres) that demands that every `NOT NULL` column also uses a `DEFAULT` value, which is needed for an automatic migration script we're using.

Due to the problems described in the first linked thread, I want to assure that my JPA (EclipseLink) cache does not get out of sync with the DB due to default values automatically being used upon an `INSERT INTO`. This could happen if the `INSERT INTO` completely omits a column - in that case the defined `DEFAULT` value would be used by the DB to fill the row.

I've observed that EclipseLink always seems to use all the mapped columns in the `INSERT INTO` statement, explicitly setting null values. This triggers the constraint violation as desired.

But is this guaranteed to happen or could the JPA provider decide to completely omit a column in the `INSERT INTO` statement that is mapped to a Java field containing a null value (leaving `insertable = false` annotations aside)?